# Javascript, string regex match?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have a string "test_mystring". Now I want to first check if this string starts with "test_" and if it does return rest of string, in this case "mystring".

How to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally one would use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 (?<=^test_).*
```

which would match anything (`.*`) if it's right after `test_` at the start of the string (`^`).

However, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, therefore you need to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
var myregexp = /^test_(.*)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, since I know also that after, in this example "test_" come only letters I changed it a bit. So I ended up using ^test_([a-zA-Z]+)$   .Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If I could use either of `positive lookbehind` or `capturing group` which one will be more efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.match(("test_")) != null) 
   str.replace(\1,'');
```

First line looks for match,

If found the second line replaces it with ''

**\1** is whatever matches  **("test_")**  which is the string constant itself.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can be achieved without `Regex` using simple `Javascript` code snippet like shown below:

```
// original string
var str = "test_mystring";
// result string
var res;
// this single line does the job
if(str.substring(0, 5)=="test_) res=str.substring(5);
```

Hope this may help.